# Can I manually tell google the gclid?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

Here's the scenario: visitor 1 (V1) clicks on an ad and gets a gclid as part of their __utmz cookie. V1 passes the url to visitor 2 (V2) on another computer. V2 visits the page from the specified url and therefore does not get a gclid. V2 completes the conversion, but adwords does not record the conversion as there is no gclid for V2.

If I can track all the above with some confidence, can I send the gclid from V1 to google when V2 completes their conversion?

Can I overwrite the __utmz cookie or can I add any javascript prior to the adwords conversion tracking script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is to maintain the campaign information if the user that was exposed to the ad sends the link to someone else. This is a major problem with user tracking in general and I see couple of methods that could help you to circumvent that.

First, gclid is used for adwords tracking. Theoretically you can save it in a cookie and then push it as a parameter to every URL that V1 is visiting and this way to maintain the campaign information when she shares the URL. This is possible, but the downside is that the data will appear as a new session of V1, not a new visitor (V2). From Google documentation:

> ...User A then copies this URL (containing the auto-tagging parameter)
>   and posts it in another location such as a public discussion board
>   (forum) or a social network, or sends it in an email or chat window to
>   other recipients.
>
> Next, User B clicks this link (containing the gclid value) and arrives
>   at your website. Even though User B has never been to the website
>   before, this user will have the first session attributed to the same
>   click id (gclid) value that was assigned to the original User A. In
>   this case, you see new sessions (caused by User B) from an old
>   campaign.
>
> Unfortunately there is no workaround to this scenario at the moment.
>
> *(source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4588454?hl=en)*

The downside however is that you fix a solution only for Google Adwords, while you may have campaigns on different platforms and sites that do not employ the gclid, but for which you use the UTM parameters.

Another solution I've stumble upon in the past is this one: http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/10/02/direct-monster-fix-dark-social/ This script adds a unique query string parameter to every URL. If this URL is shared, in your GA reports it will show data in a custom dimension that denotes the user that shared the URL (V1) and those that used that URL (V2). This way you can analyze the "power of sharing". The downside is that you don't see the conversion under the campaign in question on GA. Never tried this script, only read about it.

Finally, you can make your own cookie and store the campaign information there. Then, you can append it with a parameter to every page that V1 views on your site. If V1 shares it, the campaign information will pass with this parameter to V2. The downside is that you will not see the conversion under the campaign in question on GA, only the parameter. However, you can see in your conversions report how many of campaign-->referral conversions you had by looking at the URL that led to the conversions (in the Reverse Goal Path, for instance). In addition, you are able to track this way not only Adwords campaigns with referrals, but any campaign. Try this project: https://github.com/dm-guy/utm-alternative. This project will help you with creating your own campaign tracking, but not with pushing it to the URL.

Comment: in this case I need to be able to attribute as many conversions to their GA campaign and it doesn't matter how many people are involved, as long as I know which keyword/ad/etc converted. The link from support.google.com is the piece that I needed for this case, but all that information is helpful to me. Thanks for taking the time to write that all out.

Answer (score 0):

I work on AdWords conversion tracking.  Here's how I'd do it using AdWords Conversion Import...

If the GCLID is passed in the URL to V2, then the site can grab the GCLID for V2's visit and store it in a cookie (provided you craft some JS to do so).

Then, when the conversion occurs, you've got another bit of JS that collects the cookie and stores it somewhere along with the date/time of the conversion and the type of conversion (this type should match an equivalent conversion type that you've defined in your AdWords account).

Once you have this process in place, you can batch the conversion records up daily and import it into AdWords via the conversion import service (https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2998031).

Answer (score 0):

The gclid value pertains to Adwords and Adwords only.  To give credit to the converting gclid, you need to send the _ga cookie value in the URL query as such:

foo.com?_ga=1.2.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx

The x's above represent the clientID and this value needs to be cookied using JS:

```
  <script>
function() {

var coo = window.location.href.split("_ga=")[1].split('.');

var cid = coo[2]+"."+coo[3];
return cid;
}
</script>
```

Have this above the UA tracking code:

```
<script>

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-xx', {'clientId' : '<?php echo implode(".",array_slice(explode(".", $_GET["_ga"]), -2, 2)); ?>'});

</script>
```

Remember you must return the _ga cookie value in the URL in order for it fire off on this page.  What's clever is, if you can record to a database IP and the associated _ga cookie value, you can track a user across different browsers and/or devices PROVIDED they are using the same IP address.